# Stripe allowed for split payments to vendor direct to bank account in India?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, razorpay

I need to integrate the Payment gateway to the React Native mobile app India.

I am using rails 6 in Backend. As per my application, I need to do a split payment between the vendor and the platform.

The important thing is that the vendors are very small and they do not have the stripe account so I need to make the payment to their Bank Account directly without getting into their stripe account.

As per my research, I can do that [here](https://support.stripe.com/questions/accept-payments-from-bank-accounts-using-ach) but it's not possible for India.

Am I missing something, is it possible with stripe?

I also did research with [razorpay](https://razorpay.com/) and there is a gem for that [here](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-ruby).

Does anyone have experience with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make payouts to vendors you must use [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) and fund recipients must have [connected accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts). Note there are [some limitations](https://support.stripe.com/questions/stripe-india-support-for-marketplaces) on platforms in India. You can use, for example, [Custom accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts) that you manage and take advantage of [Connect Onboarding](https://stripe.com/connect/onboarding) to collect identity information, then you can collect [payout bank account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts-bank-accounts) information on your platform and manage payouts to your vendors.